# How to work Adcontrol in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I want to add advertisement in my application. I add the add control and got the ApplicationId and AdunitId from Microsoft Adverting Pubcenter.

I give that into my app, But it's not working........

Before i give that id it's shows below.

[image]

i give that id and all that it's not display.

This is my xaml code.

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="myid" AdUnitId="myid" Width="480"/>
```

How can i solve it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will only show ads if there is ad inventory available. That is, if there is a publisher publishing ads in that moment. If this is not the case, the control disappears.

You can check if this is your case by subscribing to `ErrorOcurred` event of the ad control:

```cs
private void AdControl_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)  
{  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad Error : ({0}) {1}", e.ErrorCode, e.Error);  
}
```

If the result is "No ad Available", then, that's the case.

You can try if you get better results by changing ad unit's categories. Anyway, ad inventory is usually very poor outside US.